# When i press buttons in my calculator , they work inconsistently

Tags: reactjs

Here is my logic to handle button presses.

```
hbp(e) {

let iVal = e.target.value;
switch(iVal) {
  case "=" :
        this.setState({calculate : true});
    break; 
  case "AC" :
    this.setState({opList : [],calculate : false});
    console.log(this.state.opList)
    break;
  default:
    let list = this.state.opList.concat(iVal);
            this.setState({opList : list,calculate : false});
            
}
```

Sometimes it appends the value that i want and sometimes it appends undefined.

My pen for this issue :
https://codepen.io/furkanozdemir2003/pen/QWKYMBP?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate this by clicking on the decimal point button. The issue is occurring because `e.target` is set to the `<i>` within the button if the pointer is over the element. For example, here's a `console.log`:

[image]

Since the `<i>` element does not have a `value` attribute, `e.target.value` will always be `undefined` The same is also true for the operator buttons, such as divide, multiply, add, subtract, etc.)

You can either remove the use of FontAwesome and thus the sub-elements, or update your getter to reference `currentTarget` instead:

```
let iVal = e.currentTarget.value;
```

Comment: `e.currentTarget` is less fuss

Comment: Nice catch. i didn't realise i was getting undefined only when i was pressing on top of the icon. Thanks man!